# When did argparse stop showing 'short help' for no arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

Some versions of Python's argparse print the short help when no arguments are given, others don't. How do I get consistent behavior across Python versions?

Comment: which version did ? which version does not?

Comment: In 3.3 it doesn't seem to, but in 2.7 it seems to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using subparsers, this happened in 3.3. It worked still in 3.2.3.

See http://bugs.python.org/issue16308